# Facebook Comments: get all comments URL under a domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the fb-comments URLs registered/created under a domain.

imagine various developers create new comments urls (relative to individual topics):

- div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/kb1001" ...
- div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/kb321" ...
- div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/faq/001"
- ...
- div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/faq/002" ...
- div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/about" ...

I wish to allow authors to create these without "governance", but want to have visibility of all URLs created.

Note: I'm looking for the URLs, not the comments or whatever, as I can get that via other api services

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the API. There is no such documentation either.